# Django add instance to QuerySet and randomise order

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have following query string

```
question = ChapterQuestion.objects.filter(chapter__course=course_learn.course).first()
options = ChapterQuestion.objects.filter(
        chapter__course=course_learn.course
    ).exclude(
        pk=question.pk
    ).order_by('?').all()[:3]
```

Now I want to merge `question` instance into `options` QuerySet and randoze their order to generate 4 options.

**How to add the instance to QuerySet of same model?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but something like ...?

```
x = random.randInt(4)
randQuestions = []
for count in range(x): randQuestions.add(options[count])
randQuestions.add(question)
for count in range(x,3): randQuestions.add(options[count])
```